# Finding max element lower then the average in list

Tags: list, max, average, doubly-linked-list

I want to find the max element that is lower then the average of all elements. It wasn't hard to find the max element:

```
int max (node *p) 
{
    int current = p->data;
    int next;
    if (p->next == NULL)   //The value at this node is obviously larger than a non-existent value 
    {    
        return current;
    } 
    else 
    {        
        next = max(p->next); //Recur to find the highest value from the rest of the LinkedList
    }
    if(current > next)        //Return the highest value between this node and the end of the list 
    {
        return current;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return next;
    }
}
```

but to find the max from the average of all is kind of hard for me. Yes, I could make some other function dealing with the size of the list and the average, but is it possible to do all that in a single function. All help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: By "possible to do all that in a single function" do you mean possible in one pass through the array, or literally just in the same (long) function?

Comment: Well at first I meant it literally but now I want to do it in one pass ... but both ways are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to it in two passes :

- first, write a function to compute the average of a whole list,
- then use a slightly modified max function to find the highest value below a given threshold,
- combine the two
- profit

Comment: OK, I found the average of the list, but I get some problems modifieing the max function so that can run if the element<average.